# Calling a model from another module issue

Tags: magento-1, model

I tried to call a model from another module but it returns me `false` or this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function assignData() on a non-object

This is how I call it:

```
Mage::getModel('adyen_payment/adyen_paybymail')->assignData(100);
```

The model can be found [here](https://github.com/Adyen/magento/blob/release-2.6.0/app/code/community/Adyen/Payment/Model/Adyen/PayByMail.php).  I checked the `config.xml` and I see the model tag is in the global tag.  Any idea ?

Comment: Please provide detail of assign data method, or provide full detail of class.

Comment: try this : Mage::getModel('payment/adyen_paybymail')->assignData(100);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `config.xml` the models are defined like this:

```
<models>
    <adyen>
        <class>Adyen_Payment_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>adyen_resource</resourceModel>
    </adyen>
    ....
</models>
```

so you need to get your model like this:

```
Mage::getModel('adyen/adyen_payByMail');
```

Comment: thx @Marius  ! It works !

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Mage::getModel('adyen/adyen_paybymail')->assignData(100);
```